# group by month of unix timestamp field

Tags: mysql, select, count, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get my code to output in the following format:

```
january 2012 - 34
february 2012 - 23
```

where 34 and 23 would be a count of the total rows that fall within that month that have the id_dealership of 7. I need this to output all data for every month that an assignment was ever made.

The `assignments` table structure is as follows:

```
id_dealer (int)
date_assigned (int)
```

I've tried this but it does not work at all:

```
SELECT MONTH(date_assigned), YEAR(date_assigned), COUNT(*)
FROM assignments
GROUP BY MONTH(date_assigned), YEAR(date_assigned)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
  COUNT(*)
FROM assignments
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned))
```

Comment: would you be able to have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699533/group-by-month-and-year-count-from-another-table

Comment: Wow, I didn’t think this was possible. Kudos!

Comment: how can i get output with month name e.g month = JAN & sales =20

Answer (score 1):

Your date_assigned column should be of type DATE. AFAIK MONTH works on date columns
and if you want the month name from a DATE column use : `MONTHNAME(date_assigned)`

Comment: This is not perfect solution of the problem but useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
  COUNT(*)
FROM assignments
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Can you please explain few words on how this query works

Answer (score 0):

For people who would like to output a `DATETIME` rather than a month/year combo, here's another way to solve the problem. The benefit of using `DATETIME` is that it can easily be plugged into data visualization libraries and tools.

```
SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned)), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM assignments
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The `LAST_DAY()` function returns the last day of the month for a given `DATE` or `DATETIME` value. If you'd rather grab the first day, you could select this instead: `ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1)`. It adds a day to the last date then subtracts a month.

The `1` values are column position integers -- shorthand so we don't have to type `LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned))` any more than we need to (they start at 1, not 0).

Example output:

```
|-------------------------------------------|------------------|
| LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_assigned))    | COUNT(*)         |
|-------------------------------------------|------------------|
| September 30, 2020, 12:00 AM              | 34               |
|-------------------------------------------|------------------|
| August 31, 2020, 12:00 AM                 | 23               |
|-------------------------------------------|------------------|
```