# Query multiple tables and group by month/year

Tags: mysql

I am working with 3 tables:
user(id,firstName,lastName,type,disabled)
comment(id,sender,date)
comment_recipient(comment_id,user_id)

I'm trying to find data on users that have given or received comments for a given month/year. My desired result row: 
First Name | Last Name | Comments Given | Comments Received | Month | Year

A single comment can have multiple recipients(many entries in comment_recipient)

I started by following this question, which seemed somewhat similar:
[group-by-month-and-year-count-from-another-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699533/group-by-month-and-year-count-from-another-table)

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
  firstName AS 'First Name',
  lastName AS 'Last Name',
  given AS 'Comments Given',
  received AS 'Comments Received',
  MONTHNAME(d_yearmonth) AS Month,
  YEAR(d_yearmonth) AS Year
FROM (
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(c.date) AS d_yearmonth,
    u.firstName,
    u.lastName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment AS c1 WHERE c1.sender=c.sender
    AND LAST_DAY(c1.date)=d_yearmonth) AS given,
    '24' AS received
  FROM comment AS c
  JOIN comment_recipient AS cr ON cr.comment_id=c.id
  JOIN user AS u ON u.id=c.sender
  WHERE u.type<4 AND u.disabled=0
  GROUP BY
    d_yearmonth
) AS s
ORDER BY Year DESC,
MONTH(d_yearmonth) DESC
```

I'm just using '24' for 'received' at the moment as I'm trying to figure this out 1 piece at a time

I don't need to count every user or every month, so if they would return 0 for both given and received, they can be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem would be a lot easier to solve if you break it in two parts.

1. Compute the number of messages sent by user, per month
2. Compute the number of message received by user, per month

The you can use a union "merge" the sent and received messages.

The full query could look like:

```
SELECT user_id,
       lastName,
       firstName,
       SUM(sent) as sent,
       SUM(received) as received,
       year,
       month 

FROM (

  SELECT 
       c.sender as user_id,
       u.lastname as lastName,
       u.firstname as firstName,
       count(*) as sent,
       0 as received,
       YEAR(date) as year, 
       MONTH(date) as month
FROM Comment as C
  JOIN user AS u ON u.id=c.sender
  WHERE u.type<4 AND u.disabled=0
GROUP by user_id, year, month

UNION ALL 

select cr.user_id as user_id, 
       u.lastname as lastName,
       u.firstname as firstName,
       0 as sent,
       count(*) as received,
       YEAR(date) as year, 
       MONTH(date) as month
FROM comment_recipient cr
JOIN comment c ON c.id = cr.comment_id
JOIN user u on u.id = cr.user_id
WHERE u.type<4 AND u.disabled=0
GROUP by user_id, year, month
) A
GROUP by user_id, year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to join together three summary datasets generated from your tables. They are

1. the set of end-of-month dates
2. the summary of comments sent.
3. the summary of comments received.

Then you can join them all together

You'll need a subquery for each of these. Start with the end-of-month dates.

```
                        SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment
```

You'll need the comments sent, summarized by userid and month

```
                        SELECT COUNT(*) sent, 
                               sender id, 
                               LAST_DAY(`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment
                         GROUP BY sender, LAST_DAY(`date`)
```

You'll need the comments received, summarized by userid and month. That requires joining to the comment table, to get the dates of the comments.

```
                        SELECT COUNT(*) received, 
                               cr.user_id id, 
                               LAST_DAY(c.`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment_recipient cr
                          JOIN comment c ON cr.comment_id = c.id
                         GROUP BY cr.user_id, LAST_DAY(c.`date`)
```

Then you need to join these three subqueries (think of them as virtual tables) with the user table.

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, 
       ISNULL(s.sent,0) sent,
       ISNULL(r.received,0) received, 
       MONTHNAME(d.month_end), YEAR(d.month_end)
  FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment
       ) AS d
  JOIN user u ON 1=1
  LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT COUNT(*) sent, 
                               sender id, 
                               LAST_DAY(`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment
                         GROUP BY sender, LAST_DAY(`date`)
            ) s ON d.month_end=s.month_end AND u.id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT COUNT(*) received, 
                               cr.user_id id, 
                               LAST_DAY(c.`date`) month_end
                          FROM comment_recipient cr
                          JOIN comment c ON cr.comment_id = c.id
                         GROUP BY cr.user_id, LAST_DAY(c.`date`)
            ) r ON d.month_end=r.month_end AND u.id = r.id
 WHERE u.type < 4 AND u.disabled = 0
   AND NOT (r.received IS NULL AND s.sent IS NULL) 
   AND d.month_end > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

It's a little tricky to get all the rows you need. That's why we have the ISNULL and LEFT JOIN operations. We also have to do the aggregates in separate queries. If we simply join comments and recipients we'll end up with a lot of duplicates.