# how to make a query in sql to use in c++ code on counting the borrowing report in every month

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I want to make a query to count borrowing report every month . But i'd saved my data in unixtime.

```
tablename:borrow
attributes:borrowingID,dateOfBorrow,dateOfReturn,statusBook
```

For example the dateOfBorrow is 167077440 and i just want to count the specific month for jan,feb,etc..

i am expecting

```
| Month | Total |
| ------| ----- |
|  Jan  |   2   |
|  Feb  |   5   |
|  Mar  |   5   |
...etc
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698977/group-by-month-of-unix-timestamp-field

Answer (score 0):

```
select from_unixtime(167077440),from_unixtime(167077440,'%b')

+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(167077440) | from_unixtime(167077440,'%b') |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1975-04-18 19:24:00      | Apr                           |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

See manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

But are you really interested in 1975?

Comment: no sir. i just give that for example